Enabling Winforms Application Windows authentication service
enter image description here
Hi,
I want to add windows authentication to my Winforms Application. I have gone to properties and enabled this as shown in the screenshot. Want to test if its working or not. How do i proceed?
For now i have just created a new winforms application and gone to properties then services and enabled the above as shown in the screenshot. Just want to know to test it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
